# What conditions does the cloud function automatically extend the instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

The docs https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#concurrency says:

> Cloud Functions can start multiple function instances to scale up to meet the current load.

But it's not clear about what conditions will cause cloud function scale up?

How do I control the count of the instances for cloud function?

What if I don't want cloud function scale up automatically, how can I do this?

Comment: OK. After a month later, GCP release the new features for cloud function. Now, you can control scale behavior. Here is the docs: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/max-instances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But it's not clear about what conditions will cause cloud function scale up?

It's based on the load being applied to the function.  The details are not documented and could change over time.

> How do I control the count of the instances for cloud function?

You can't - it's based on the active load.

> What if I don't want cloud function scale up automatically, how can I do this?

You can't.  The scaling is automatic.

Comment: Thanks. It's sad to hear this. Because if I don't control the instances of cloud function. The count of db connection will over the limit of cloud SQL.  The pool size of cloud SQL is 100. Assume one instance of cloud function use one pool.

Comment: Cloud SQL might not be your best companion database for a serverless backend, then.

Comment: What active load will scale up cloud function? Memory? request count? How can I test it?

Comment: As I said, it's not documented.  The system determines the best time.  If you're not comfortable letting the system scale up and down for you, you probably shouldn't be using a serverless backend.  Use something where you take control.